# Storing looping rows in R

Tags: r

```
laststop <- NULL
stopinfo <- NULL
for (i in journeys$JourneyID){
  laststop <- get_last_stop(i)
  stopinfo <- c(stop_info(i,laststop))
  final_stops <- data.frame(stopinfo)
  }
```

Basically, through `stop_info` function with two variables `laststop` and `I`, I can get a output 1 row with 8colums. I can get only one row with this `data.freme` code above. What I want to get is a complete dataframe named `final_stops`. when I type `rint(final_stops)`, I can see the whole 300 outcomes I need.
But I don't know how to make it into the complete dataframe

Comment: Maybe you can create an empty data.frame before the loop and use `rbind()` to add the row of each iteration? It's difficult to tell without a data example and the custom functions

Comment: I'd say laststop and stopinfo would be empty lists `laststop <- list()`, for (i in 1:length(ljourney$JourneyID)){ laststop[[i]] <- , then I'm lost with `get last stop`. Perhaps `dput(head(my_data))`, then copy output `structure(....)` here as data.

Comment: I have already got iterate rows, can I just make it into data frame?

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to tell if you do not show a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But, assuming you get every iteration a data.frame of one row, same columns and you would like to have all of them together, you could use `rbind()`:

```
laststop <- NULL
stopinfo <- NULL
for (i in journeys$JourneyID){
  laststop <- get_last_stop(i)
  stopinfo <- c(stop_info(i,laststop))
  if (i==1){  # If it is the first iteration: creates the variable
  final_stops <- data.frame(stopinfo)
  }   # if it is second or later iteration, bind by row
  else {
    final_stops <- rbind(final_stops , data.frame(stopinfo)) # combine rows
  }
}
```

However, this is probably not the best solution and likely you could apply your functions in a tidyverse/data.frame operations much cleaner way. But with custom functions and not a data example, impossible to say.